# Local Settings in Windows 7 Roaming Profiles

Tags: roaming-profile, windows-7

We're planning a migration of several hundred desktops to Windows 7 and hitting a snag in our test lab with roaming profiles. Bit of background:

- Win 2003 FFL
- Currently all XP machines
- Roaming profiles, working fine
- Win7 test PCs are in Computer container, not in seperate OU so as yet not affected by a myriad of GPO.

We've just started using a few test machines both here in our office and in test. The profile directory is created on the server as username.V2 but contains ALL of the profile, including Local and LocalLow. For many users this consists of many gigs of Outlook cache!

Does anyone have any thoughts? I thought Windows was meant to exclude these dirs by default?

Comment: Microsoft likes to do things in certain ways. Maybe the test container for your Win7 is causing this? Maybe there's an implied/embedded/default GPO rule somewhere that you are now bypassing? Also, have you updated the win2003 server with all the bits needed to support Windows7? And overall, it might be more cost effective to setup a new Windows 2008 server first.

Answer (score 0):

The Local and LocalLow aren't supposed to roam with the user. M$ has said that the data stored in these folders are usually too large to roam.  See this:

[Managing Roaming User Data Deployment Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20120419100553/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I've read the articles as well - I know full well that they're not *supposed* to roam, but they still are. Which is the problem :-)

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I got nothing then. gl